# How do I upload PowerPoint slideshow files in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have some PowerPoint slideshow files, .ppsx, with mime-type `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow`, that I want to upload to WordPress. However, when I try to upload it to the media browser, I get the error "Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.".

This is despite the fact that .ppsx files are in the list of allowed file types and mimetypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upload a file, WordPress does some security checks on the file in the [wp_check_filetype_and_ext](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_check_filetype_and_ext/) function in `wp-include/functions.php:2503`. Part of these checks is to validate the given mimetype of the file with the mimetype that PHP detects, using the PHP function [finfo_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php).

However, `finfo_file()` isn't always accurate, and its results are often OS dependent. In the specific case of .ppsx files, `finfo_file()` can read the mimetype as `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation`. WordPress sees this as a potential security risk because it doesn't match the given mimetype for that file extension and shuts down the upload.

`wp_check_filetype_and_ext()` also has a filter, and we can use this to our advantage:

```
function my_check_filetype_and_ext( $info, $file, $filename, $mimes, $real_mime )
{
    if ( empty( $check['ext'] ) && empty( $check['type'] ) )
    {
        $secondaryMimetypes = ['ppsx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'];

        // Run another check, but only for our secondary mime and not on core mime types.
        remove_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'my_check_filetype_and_ext', 99, 5 );
        $info = wp_check_filetype_and_ext( $file, $filename, $secondaryMimetypes );
        add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'my_check_filetype_and_ext', 99, 5 );
    }

    return $info;
}
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'my_check_filetype_and_ext', 99, 5 );
```

In vanilla WordPress, there is no way to have multiple mimetypes for a single filetype. The above filter runs the mimetype checks again for a secondary set of filetype/mimetype pairs if it fails the first set of pairs. By allowing .ppsx files with the presentation mimetype, you can now upload .ppsx files!

Comment: You have a lowercase "t" in the $secondaryMimetypes declaration but using it with an uppercase in $info.

Thanks for this though.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add some code in your configure.php file to upload any type of

```
define( 'ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true );
```

Add this in your configure.php file and you will be able to upload any file format.

or you can follow this [link](https://niamrox.com/how-to-fix-sorry-this-file-type-is-not-permitted-for-security-reasons-error-in-wordpress/)

Answer (score -1):

Following code work fine for me.

```
function wcAddCustomFileTypeAndExt( $info, $file, $filename, $mimes, $real_mime )
{
    if (strpos($filename, '.ppsx') !== false) 
    {
        $info['ext'] = 'ppsx';
        $info['type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow';
    }
    return $info;
}
add_filter('wp_check_filetype_and_ext','wcAddCustomFileTypeAndExt', 99, 5 );
```